# Trigger command not working in sign as non-operator

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I am creating a minigame in Minecraft 1.16.3 via a datapack and mcfunctions.

I want to make command-signs that a player can click on to change settings.

I use the Trigger-command to make it accessible to non-operator players.

I also enabled the trigger-objective via `scoreboard players enable @a team`

The command `trigger team set 3` works fine when executed in chat by a non-operator, **but** when the non-operator player clicks the sign with the same command set as clickEvent nothing happens.

When an operator clicks the same sign it works.

It seems like you have to be an operator to execute any command inside a sign and I can't find away around it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "ignore-vanilla-permissions" to "false" in commands.yml :)

You're welcome !

Comment: I am using a vanilla server. There is no commands.yml